# Installing a module in Python using the source file (*.tar.gz)

Tags: python, pdfminer

My PC runs Windows10 and I have installed the following version of Python via Anaconda 3: Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)

I am trying to install pdfminer.six but I am running into an exception:

[image]

I don't know what is the cause of this exception.

I was thinking to try to install pdfminer.six using the source file `pdfminer.six-20170720.tar.gz` (md5) which can be found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfminer.six/20170720

I have downloaded but I do not know how to install it.

Comment: The error indicates your `html5lib` version is out of date. `pip` normally bundles its own version as a vendored library, perhaps Anaconda overrides that and manages `html5lib` versions directly.

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/588:  `conda update pip` should fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can still use `pip` to install downloaded source archives or wheels. Just point `pip` to the file:

```
pip install pdfminer.six-20170720.tar.gz
```

As for *why* your `pip` installation is broken: Due to path length issues on Windows, Anaconda had moved the `pip` *vendored packages* to normal dependencies (`pip` vendors packages to avert problems exactly like you have now).

You then installed a package (like Tensorflow), that requires an older version of one of the `pip` dependencies, `html5lib`. This caused everything to break, horribly.

You should be able to fix the `pip` issue with

```
conda update pip
```

as the newer version has returned to vendored dependencies (after a bugfix upstream that avoids the path length issues).

For more details, see [this issue in the Tensorflow project](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/588), which is one such project that needed an older `html5lib` version and triggered the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pip` command to install from the downloaded .gz file.

**Ex:**

```
pip install pdfminer.six-20170720.tar.gz
```

Comment: On Windows, I sometimes have to add `python -m` in front of the `pip` call.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: both `pip` and `python -m pip` are valid ways of invoking the tool; the former essentially does the latter, but if it is not available on your path, the latter is fine.

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke: but note that the OP had no issues with finding the `pip` command, only with running the command.